# In D3.js how do I append a text element after having changed the attributes of my path element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the following code:

```
  svg
    .selectAll('mySlices')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
      .attr('d', arcGenerator)
      .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("opacity", 0.7)
```

And I'd like to append text elements right after each of my path elements.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
  svg
    .selectAll('mySlices')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
      .attr('d', arcGenerator)
      .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("opacity", 0.7)
    .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.key})
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcGenerator.centroid(d) + ")";  })
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", 10)
```

What's important to me is that each text element immediately follow the respective path element in the document so I can use the + CSS Sibling selector to show text on hover of the path element.

I'm open to alternatives, but can't think of any.

Ultimately I just want to display the text on hover for each pie segment.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can keep track of the selection storing it as a variable. The difference is that d3 working chaining and applying functions. You also need to add the class name for your selection, in case you want to select them.

```js
 const slices = svg
    .selectAll('.mySlices')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
      .attr('d', arcGenerator)
      .attr('fill', function(d){ return(color(d.data.key)) })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("opacity", 0.7)
      .attr("class", "mySlices");

   slices.append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .text(function(d){ return d.data.key})
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcGenerator.centroid(d) + ")";  })
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", 10);
```

Comment: Doesn't that result in the path elements being together and then the text elements being together? <path><path><path><text><text><text> Instead of <path><text><path><text><path><text>